# Holo Theme and API 8

Tags: android

I have an app that must be supported from API 8+. But I also like to have my app the holo theme for(11+). I know it won't be supported as the min sdk is 8. So the only solution will be to create 2 separate apps one for 8-11 and one for 11+. Is there any better way to do this? So that I can reduce double maintenance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's no need to create two separate apps. You just need to create two definitions of theme for your app:

styles.xml in /res/values-v11 (Will be used only on API 11+)

```
<resources>
    <style name="app_theme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light"/>
</resources>
```

styles.xml in /res/values

```
<resources>
    <style name="app_theme" parent="android:Theme.Light"/>
</resources>
```

and then, apply it to your application in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
        ...
        android:theme="@style/app_theme"
        >
  ...
</application>
```

This setup uses resource qualifiers. You can read more about them [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html).

Comment: I guess I asked a stupid question. I should have known about this. This works like a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can try the [HoloEverywhere library](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere) to use Holo theme on Android 2.1+. It also integrates well with [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/).