# Incorrect theme is applied to AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to create a new alertbox with a loading symbol in my android application. Working fine. Below is my code.

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, null));
progress = new ProgressBar(this);
builder.setMessage("Message");
builder.setView(progress);
//builder.setCancelable(false);
builder.create().show();
```

My Custom.XML looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

<ProgressBar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="32dp"
             android:layout_height="32dp"
             android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My res/styles.xml is

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="maxWid">
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>

        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">50dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">50dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">10dp</item>
    </style>
    <style name="apBtn">
        <item name="android:textColor">#000</item>
        <item name="android:layout_alignParentLeft">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

res/values-v11/styles.xml is

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme for API 11+. This theme completely replaces
        AppBaseTheme from res/values/styles.xml on API 11+ devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

res/values-v14/styles.xml is

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
        AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
        res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

My AndroidManifest.cml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myapp.kmc"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.myapp.kmc.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.myapp.kmc.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.kmc.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.kmc.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.kmc.ListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_list"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.kmc.CompleteActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_complete"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.myapp.kmc" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.myapp.kmc.GCMIntentService" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.kmc.RegisterDevice"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_register_device" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Testing in android 4.1.2

But when I create a new application and follow this code I am getting an alert box like this

[image]

But When I implement the same code in my existing application. I am getting an alert box like this

[image]

Since I want the first one in my existing application. Its ruining my time..

Can any one please help me. I am new to android
Thanks in advance

Comment: check with android versions, themes. the first one looks like holo theme

Comment: Which android version device you have?

Comment: Hi, I am checking both application in android 4.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your existing application uses `Theme.Black`, that's why dialog has black background. Change theme to `Theme.Holo.Light` to fix it.

For recommended way to do this, take a look at my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16633076/1318939).

---

**EDIT:** Looks like you're applying the correct theme to your `<application>` tag, but then you're overriding it by setting `Theme.NoTitleBar` (which is a descendant of `Theme.Black`) to each of your activities.

Remove `android:theme` attribute from `<activity>` tags and it will work. 
If you want to remove title and action bar, apply [`windowNoTitle`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowNoTitle) and [`windowActionBar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowActionBar) attributes to your theme definition:

```
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
```

Comment: hi thanks for the reply.. I am new to this. From where I can change the theme ?

Comment: @ramesh the answer I linked to explains this in details.

Comment: I tried that but not working . Also my res/styles.xml has been updated in my question.. Can you please have a look ?

Comment: @ramesh your style declarations look ok. The problem might be with `AndroidManifest.xml`. Please provide it in your question.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply... I just updated my question. Please have a look

Comment: Hi one more problem.. when I tried this, my complete UI, image button and all get stretched vertically.. any idea ? When I removed  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

Comment: @ramesh can't say without looking at screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

If  you want to use Holo Theme you must set your API level to 14 (that has hardware acceleration enabled as default);

Try to insert:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />
```

At your AndroidManifest.xml.