# Eclipse with ADT - Cannot Create New Android Project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-adt

I'm totally new to Android development, but I've made apps with Java and Eclipse before. Today I was trying to follow a neat tutorial @ KiloBolt (http://www.kilobolt.com/day-1-foundations) formaking and Android game. However, I have this issue that I don't understand preventing me from following along.

Every time I try and create a new Android project in Eclipse, I get to the following screen and cannot press FINISH or NEXT. I have the ADT plugin installed and the Android SDK installed, along with a Java 7 JDK. Eclipse doesn't show any other errors that I know of.

[image]

Does anyone know what I might be missing or why Eclipse won't let me create a new Android project?

EDIT: Following Daniel's comment about themes and Android versions, I retried creating a project with the theme set to 'None', but I was still blocked from continuing.

[image]

Comment: Looks like you can't use that theme with a min sdk set to 9. Either choose a different theme, or increase the min sdk value. Or, separate out the style xml files, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633039/holo-theme-and-api-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment says, you can't use the Holo Theme with Minimum Required SDK 9. You need at least Minimum Required SDK 14 to use the Holo Theme.

Anyway, you're following a very old tutorial. I strongly recommend you to create a new project with Android Studio instead of Eclipse. It will just work and it will use a more modern structure with gradle (although you will need some time to learn how to use Android Studio)

This is a good place to start: https://medium.com/google-developers/getting-started-with-android-using-android-studio-in-preparation-for-a-zombie-apocalypse-8f42cae10644

Comment: I ended up switching to Android studio as you suggested, and it's actually working! Good call, thank you!